# Jquery datatable export buttons not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to add the export button of excel and pdf in a jquery data table with help of its extension but buttons are not appearing above the table .I tried many other links but still not able to resolve

```
var ticketingTableR= $('#ticketingTableR').DataTable( {
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
      buttons: [
          'copy','pdf','excel'
        ],
      columns: [
            { title: "TKT#" },
            { title: "Name" },
            { title: "Email" },
            { title: "Type" },
            { title: "Status" },
            { title: "Created At" },
            { title: "Completed At" }
        ],
        
  
      "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
            "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
            "paging":   true,
            "ordering": true,
  
           "ajax": {
               "url": "{{ url('/getTicketingSupervisor') }}",
               "type": "POST",
               data: {"_token": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
              },
           },
           "scrollY": 400,
           "scrollX": true
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Include these js and css.

**CSS**

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.4/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
```

**JS**

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/js/dataTables.responsive.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
```

**script changes**

Also change this line to

`'copy','pdf','excel'` to `'copy','pdf','excel', 'csv'`